# Host header vulnerability web2py

Tags: security, http, web2py, hostheaders

Forget password and user verification code has host header vulnerability.

Attacker can generate user verification and password reset request from the server including his own domain.

Is their a better way out??

https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problems solution as an multi tear security approach.

Apache acts as an gate keeper. Which if configured properly can restrict anonymous host headers routed to the application. (still not sure about the cache injections)

Though online anonymous domain host headers may not posses any threat to the application in https scenario.

but offline request like forget password email reset request do posses a big threat. Because evil attacker can request forget password email reset over an anonymous domain host headers. Then if the actual user clicks the password reset link. Evil attacker will get hold of the reset code.

Now here application is relying on the host headers routed by the Apache for creating offline response. That should not happen (apache should be held responsible for online traffic). Thus application should have its own mechanism for domain name configuration and creating offline responses.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as mentioned in the issue, the `Host` header should be set by the server rather than the request object.

In this case, you could have a virtual host (vhost) that will catch any requests that use an unrecognized host name. The implementation varies according to the web server however you can view the links on how to go about this on [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#) and [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html#defaultallports).

More information regarding host header attacks can be found [here](https://acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/host-header-attack).

Comment: So their are two types of security measures global: where apache virtual host is configured for catching any unrecognised host name request.
then also a local security measures: where application itself should avoid SERVER_NAME instead of the Host header.

Comment: @Abhisheietk - Did this answer your question? If so, could you please accept it so that we may close this post.

Comment: Web2py have been patched in order to resolve the host header vulnerability. Apache config is indeed a first defence of an attack.